# How do I get quarried stone?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I can't find anywhere to get quarried stone to build my house on the hearthfire expansion so I would like to know lots of places to get it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Near any house plot in Skyrim Hearthfire there is a quarry in the direct vicinity of the house plot.

As example, for the house plot in Falkreath, the quarry is directly next to the construction bench. You just need a pickaxe to quarry it. Fortunately there is a pickaxe right next to it.

There are some other places too in the world, but I don't think it would make much sense listing them because of what I said above.

Quarries also provide an infinite amount of "Quarried Stone", so you don't have to go anywhere else.

Comment: I'm sure the quarries aren't really specifically unlimited, but it gives you 4000 stone each month and that's why I seems unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a quarry right near your plot, with a pickaxe laying right next to it.

It will never run out of stone so you have an unlimited amount and you'll get 4 stones every 3 seconds!

As a bonus, here is a map link : http://srmap.uesp.net/?centeron=Gray+Pine+Goods

Answer (score 0):

The [steward of your home](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Personal_Steward) can supply you with Quarried Stone and other building materials. They will sell 20 units of Quarried Stone for 100 gold.

Comment: Why down vote? Maybe because he doesn't need a steward but to find a place for quarry.

Comment: Not sure why there are downvotes. This information seems to be correct. As per https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Personal_Steward and https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Miscellaneous_Items#Quarried_Stone - Quarried Stone can be bought from the steward of your home.